# react-native-vector-icons IOS include some

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, icons, react-native-vector-icons

I want to include only AntDesign and maybe FontAwesome icons in my project, the documentation says that if i use auto linking i need to add this to my react-native.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  dependencies: {
    'react-native-vector-icons': {
      platforms: {
        ios: null,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

so i did I want to have AntDesign available 100% is this goiong to be enough to do it like so?

```
module.exports = {
  dependencies: {
    'react-native-vector-icons': {
      platforms: {
        ios: ['AntDesign.ttf'],
      },
    },
  },
};
```

or is it not necessary? I asked chatGPT and it says that passing null means that thise fonts would be dowloaded at runtime from some remote server, is that not the case for android? Android seems to favour including them all without making a fuss about bundle size. Should i worry about bundling them, what would be more performant to have them downloaded every time or bundled?

Thanks